# Can I dynamically name my mongo collections from Java?

Tags: java, mongodb

So I have a basic getter-setter java class. Let's call is 'EarningClass'. So I know I can use @Document(collection="earnings") to set the collection name.

Now for some testing I am doing I want to dynamically in my JUnit change it to be "test_earnings" or something like that so that I can keep my test data separate but still in the same database. Is there a way to dynamically set collection names to be persisted to mongo?